# Nvm no me deja instalar la última version de node de 64 bits

Tags: nodejs, windows10, nvm

instale de forma manual node 10.15.3-x64, en Windows 10 de 64 bits, pero después escuche que node  maneja  muchas versiones por  lo que  es  mas recomendable utilizar nvm.

Instale nvm versión 1.1.7, pero cuando intento instalar  la ultima versión de node por medio  de nvm utilizando:

```
nvm install lastest
```

me envía el error

> Node.js vlastest.0.0 is only available in 32-bit.

¿Hay forma de instalar la última versión de node con nvm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creo que el comando correcto es:

```
nvm install latest
```

Yo tengo una máquina igual con Windows 10 de 64 bits y hace tiempo me funcionó con ese comando.